# Form validation - Inline bubble to capture error message from server

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm building a login page and I’ve been experimenting with HTML5 form validation feature. I like the bubble inline error message e.g. at input element for type "email" & "password". I customzed those messages without any problem. My problem is capturing the response message from the server side upon submission and display them as inline bubble message just below the 'Sign In' button.

Sample of the image.

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure how to force the server error response message to be captured as an inline bubble just below the 'Sign in' button below.
Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Codes:

```
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function init() {
    document.getElementById("email").focus();
 }
 function showerror(input) {
    if (document.getElementById("email").childNodes.item(0).value.length == 0) {
        input.setCustomValidity("Please fill out this field");
    } else {
        input.setCustomValidity("Please enter a valid email address");
    }

}
 </script>
 </head>

 <body onload="init();showx()">
<br />
<br />
<br />
<header>
    <div id="header-center-11x12">
        <img id="goeasyhome_logo_12x12" src="/images/goeasyhome_basic.png"
            alt="goeasyhome" />
    </div>
</header>

<br />
<div id="main-content">
    <form method="post" action="j_security_check">
        <div id="email">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="j_username"
                pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}"
                oninvalid="showerror(this)" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"
                required="required" />
        </div>
        <div id="password">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="j_password"
                required="required" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="signin">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <br /> <a class="passwdsignup-color" href="/forgotpassword.jsp">Forgot
        Password? </a> <a class="passwdsignup-color signup-position"
        href="/signup.jsp">Sign Up?</a>
</div>
 </body>
```